# Xcode 7.0.1 Unknown Class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

After updating to Xcode 7.0.1 identifying the custom class of a ViewController.swift file for a scene in Storyboard returns an error `Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.`

- Typing `ViewController` into the `Identity Inspector` for the scene does not autocomplete.
- Cleaning the build does not help.
- Caching the derived build folder does not help.
- Deleting the app from the simulator does not help.
- Adding a different storyboard to the project does not help.

Has anyone else encountered the bug? If so, what solution did you employ to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a CocoaTouchClass instead of a Swift file solved the problem. Is there any reason why the .swift file does not work?